# C# get file change events

Tags: c#, file-io

I do have a program which logs some specific events in a text file (it keeps the file open).
Now I want to program a second application which shows these logs on a form.

can I set an event for any change in a text file which is opened by another process? or I have to read that regularly?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)