# tracking file size change in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# get file change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948542/c-sharp-get-file-change-events)

i want to track a specific file size when it reach a specific size using C#
is there a way to add event handler on file size change or do i need to run an infinite process in thread that keeps checking the file size ?
thanks

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch for changes to your file. When it changes, get the size. For example:

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\pathtoyourfile");
fsw.Changed += TheFileChanged;


private void TheFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
    {
        var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        var theSize = info.Length;
    }
}
```

When you are done watching for changes, dispose of your FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and handle the [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) event. Then you would need to compare the file size only when necessary.

[**FileSystemWatcher-Tutorial**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/filesystemwatcher)

Comment: +1 for the tutorial, presenting the solution is not the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). This can be used to raise an event when a file changes. Its typical use would be some thing like

```
// Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = args[1];

// Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
// the renaming of files or directories.
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
// Only watch text files.
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

// Begin watching.
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Then add the relevent `EventHandler`s

```
// Define the event handlers. 
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class and [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) event.

Also there is a cool project called [.NET File System Watcher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2157/A-NET-File-System-Watcher).

[image]