# how do i find the size of a file as it is being created. I need to know if the user is adding to the file currently

Tags: c#

I am working in Windows 10 platform using c#.  I'm developing a method that will monitor video files being created. I want to know when they are complete and when they are being created. The files are very large and so I think I should be able to get the size of the file and then 5 seconds later check to see if it has grown.

```
private void main()
{
    string file = Path.Combine(roomPath, currentFile);
    FileInfo fil = new FileInfo(file);
    double previousSize = fil.Length;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    string file2 = Path.Combine(roomPath, currentFile);
    FileInfo fil2 = new FileInfo(file2);
    double currentSize = fil2.Length;
}
```

I expected to get a snapshot of the size of the file at 2 different instances but, although the file should be much larger after 5 seconds they are both the same.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725405/tracking-file-size-change-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: Well, You can make a function that runs every five seconds, Than store the file size in a variable(such as oldFileSize) than in the next loop check the current file size and if it's larger than the oldFileSize variable call a function and set the oldFileSize variable to the current file size.

Comment: You could try opening the file for writing (without writing to it). That should fail if another program currently has it open.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Hannan. I did not see this answer because I did not know how to phrase the question, but that is the perfect solution